# Amazon Web Services Apache Server

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get a feel for the costs imposed by running apache on AWS continually. Assuming that the service is scarcely used, does anyone know how many cpu hours that would eat up in a month just by sitting there and running? I understand that this is slightly impractical but I am trying to figure out what the cost of entry is to deploy an application on this platform (as compared to GAE). I suspect it to be small but I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon charges for EC2 instances by uptime, not CPU time.  The cheapest Linux instance type costs 8.5c / hour, or about $37 / month.  You can reduce this by either signing up for a [reserved instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/) that you plan to run for an extended period, or by using a [spot priced instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/) where you bid the price you're prepared to pay.

You will also incur bandwidth charges for data transfer in and out of the EC2 network, and storage charges if you store any data permanently on AWS.  These should be small compared with the cost of running the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have an estimates here:
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html